# ui-sortable acting strange with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-sortable

In my AngularJS application I created a [`ui-sortable`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) with a list. When I try to order the list different, it is acting stange. Without a `ng-model` I do not have this problem, but `ui-sortable` requires to have a `ng-model`, otherwise it will print an error in the console. Why does the ng-model create this problem? Do I have created my model object in a wrong?

I reproduces the error in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxAre/021hynqm/) jsFiddle.

**To reproduce**: drag Laurent to the bottom of the list, and Laurent will appear in the middle, and not on the bottom where it should be.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in ui-sortable, you're using an extremely oudated version of the both libraries.
check out the source code at
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/v0.0.1/src/sortable.js
and compare it with your version
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js
after some debuging you might notice there is

```
onStop = function(e, ui) {
            // digest all prepared changes
            if (ui.item.sortable.resort && !ui.item.sortable.relocate) {

              // Fetch saved and current position of dropped element
              var end, start;
              start = ui.item.sortable.index;
              end = ui.item.index();
              if (start < end)
                end--;

              // Reorder array and apply change to scope
              ui.item.sortable.resort.$modelValue.splice(end, 0, ui.item.sortable.resort.$modelValue.splice(start, 1)[0]);

            }
            if (ui.item.sortable.resort || ui.item.sortable.relocate) {
              scope.$apply();
            }
          };
```

remove that if statement start < end then end-- and it will work. onStop should look like this after

```
 onStop = function(e, ui) {
            // digest all prepared changes
            if (ui.item.sortable.resort && !ui.item.sortable.relocate) {

              // Fetch saved and current position of dropped element
              var end, start;
              start = ui.item.sortable.index;
              end = ui.item.index();

              // Reorder array and apply change to scope
              ui.item.sortable.resort.$modelValue.splice(end, 0, ui.item.sortable.resort.$modelValue.splice(start, 1)[0]);

            }
            if (ui.item.sortable.resort || ui.item.sortable.relocate) {
              scope.$apply();
            }
          };
```

I do not recommend manual changes to library code, rather upgrade to new version of the code, there might be more features and more bug fixes.

Comment: I updated the sortable.js file to the [latest release](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/releases/tag/v0.19.0) locally, but the problem does still exist. It reacts the same as before..

Comment: update angular, and jquery and jquery-ui as per requirements of ui-sortable and try agian.

Comment: Give me a new fiddle. Your example is very straight forward. If its not working, that would mean ui-sortable is broken, which it isn't as its working on the demo site.